# Insert record after Laravel form validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I'm trying a Laravel 5.8 request validation. I managed to return errors and display them to my view. The problem is when I try to not trigger any validation rule, for whatever reason I cannot insert records into my table.

**Error**

> Too few arguments to function
>   App\Http\Requests\FieldRequest::Illuminate\Foundation\Providers{closure}(),
>   0 passed and exactly 1 expected

**Controller**

```php
class FormController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }

    public function store(FieldRequest $req)
    {
        $validate_data = $req->validate();

        Form::create($validate_data);

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Success!');
    }
}
```

**FormRequest**

```php
class FieldRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'item_name' => 'bail|required|max:255',
            'sku_no' => 'required|alpha_num',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'item_name.required' => 'An Item Name is required',
            'sku_no.required' => 'An SKU NO is required',
            'price.required' => 'The price is required',
        ];
    }
}
```

I'm expecting something to be inserted in my table. Do I need to perform the validation in my controller or not to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you put your request code

Comment: Wait ill edit my post above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```php
    public function store(FieldRequest $req)
    {
          $data = $req->all();           

          Form::create($data);

          return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Success!');
    }
```

when you are working with form request you no need to use `validate()` function because your request goes in form request to validate your data then it will store records

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps me a lot. I know this may sound out of my original post, is there a specific rule on where to perform the validation. I still want to perform the validation in my controller but there are post suggests that the validation should be on a separate file like the request and inject it to your controller?